# Find all $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z}=7\mathbb{Z}$ where $\zeta=e^{(i\pi/3)}$

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Find all $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z}=7\mathbb{Z}$ where $\zeta=e^{(i\pi/3)}.$

I determined that the minimal polynomial is $f(x)=x^2-x+1$. Since $f(\zeta)=0$ and $f$ is an irreducible quadratic it must be the minimal polynomial.

Then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$. Since this is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ it has the same Krull dimension, namely $1$.  Primes of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ are primes of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that contain $(x^2-x+1)$ so all primes in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ look like $(q,x^2-x+1)$ where $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime. Thus there is only a single prime $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z}=7\mathbb{Z}$, namely $(7,x^2-x+1)$, which is the ideal $(7)\subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

Somehow the wording of the problem "find all prime ideals and give generators" made me expect more... Is this correct? Many thanks for an answer.

Comment: Modulo $7$ we have the factorization $x^2-x+1\equiv (x-3)(x+2)$ so you have ideals like $(7,x-3)$ that contain $(7,x^2-x+1)$. Clearly $(7,x-3)$ is a prime ideal, but $(7,x^2-x+1)$ is not because of the above factorization.

Comment: Essentially, 7 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, is the flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: That's another correct way of looking at it! It happens that $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a PID (it's actually a Euclidean domain), but that is usually not the case. This kind of questions are studied extensively in algebraic number theory.